# What is ”size” in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, affixes, nouns

I can tell the difference betweeen a quantity and the presence of a quality.

- rapido - speed / rapideco - quickness
- longo - length / longeco - longness
- pezo - weight / pezeco - heaviness

I thought the same followed for grand-. Then, the correct word for size would be grando. But grando refers to all of the words on the left side above. It means physical quantity. How do I say size then? I searched both PIV and reta-vortaro and found no entry with a definitiom which matches what I am looking for.

> *Mi volas aĉeti ĉi tiun ĉemizon, sed mi ne trovas mian grandecon.*

Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to several non-English [translations in ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/grand.html#lng_es) *grando* means both magnitude and size.

Here are some examples from the Spanish-Esperanto Dictionary by F. de Diego:

> Kiun grandon havas la ŝuoj? [What size are the shoes?]
>
> Mi portas la grandon 43an [I wear size 43 (shoe size)]

I suppose the sentence [...] *mi ne trovas mian grandecon* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you clarified the system yourself, the correct pair is

- grando - size / grandeco - bigness

If you don't want to express that your shirt is big, but that it has the right size, your sentence should be

> Mi volas aĉeti ĉi tiun ĉemizon, sed mi ne trovas mian **grandon**.

Cf. the following quotes from the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/), where *grando* means "size":

> - la okulo erare mezuris la grandon de l’ objektoj
> - La kuirilo troviĝis en kvar grandoj
> - mi finis la mezuradon kaj kalkulojn pri la grando de la tero